# не работает & + & в SASS

Tags: html, gulp, scss, sass, webstorm

```
.helper_links {
  display: flex;
 
  li {
    & + & {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    a {
      неважно

      &:hover {
        неважно
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]
выделенные ссылки имеют отступ друг от друга только если вместо & + & написать & + li, что странно
Как исправить эти траблы с оператором &, в случаях описания селектора внутри селектора & работает, типп

```
.section-plans {

&__item {}

}
```

а & + & нет

Comment: `&` - это подстановка строки. Если посмотришь конечный css станет понятно почему полученный селектор не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[parent selector (`&`)](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) хранит в себе весь собранный селектор к текущему месту.

Для пример в вопросе

```
.helper_links {
  display: flex;
 
  li {
    & + & {
```

вместо `&` будет подставляться `.helper_links li`.

В результате для `& + &` получится

```
.helper_links li + .helper_links li
```

Как итог, стиль будет применяться к элементам `li` лежащим внутри `.helper_links`, который стоит после `li`.

Разметка должна быть примерно такая

```
<ul class="helper_links">
   <li></li>
   <ul class="helper_links">
      <li>применится к этому элементу</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Оо спасибо, теперь все понятно